# Rails migrations over an existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rails-migrations

I am creating a new Rails 3.1 application.
I would like this new application to reuses an existing database (which was created by a previous rails 2 application).

I created the new application defining models that reuses some of the existing data in the database.

In the development and test phase everything works fine since it runs on a clean sheet database, but when trying to deploy to production I get messages such as:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column "email" of relation "users" already exists
*** [err :: localhost] : ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

however I have in my migration thinks like

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable
      t.timestamps
    end
end
```

How can I make db:migrate ignore what already exist and only change the new things and/or new types?

I saw similar questions on stackoverflow, but none answering this question. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I advise you create set of migrations to duplicate existing production database, those migrations should be placed at the start of migration list, last migration in this subset should have number of the current production schema version (see `select max(version) from schema_migrations` on production database). All later migrations should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the problem here is that, for instance, ``t.recoverable`` will add fields that I do not know explicitly. Thus the need to tell rails to "add only what is missing".

Comment: You can inspect file db/schema.rb to make some idea about the schema (both in development and production).

Comment: Indeed this would work. However this means that the answer is: "no rails will not handle this, you should do it manually". Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Rails will handle this, you don't need to do anything manyally in one case: you copy all migrations from the old project to the new one. Try to keep DB constisensy over reuse DB versionning. Every db migration file have UTC timestamp as a name and the name is a DB version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using an existing database then you shouldn't try and override it through migrations, you should replicate the existing database in schema.rb and then migrate forwards from there, only adding the fields that have changed.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as "the" answer. Basically, as I understanding it Rails will not help you handling and existing database. Adding fields "by hand" is a no-go in the mentioned `t.recoverable` example.

So the short answer is: "no rails will not handle that".

Thanks for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I've taken is to create a new model (assuming you don't have any migrations yet - carefully delete them if you do), say, "rails generate model user".  Among other things, the generator creates the db migration for that model.  When you run the db migrate rails, rails creates the users table and creates a schema.rb based on the current state of the existing database.  From then on subsequent migrations will be based on the schema.rb and any new changes made.