# Heroku DB:push issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've read through a bunch of posts and googled hard but can't find a set of things to check to solve the following error when I do a:

```
heroku db:push
```

I've read this answer: [Rails migrations over an existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807172/rails-migrations-over-an-existing-database)

But it doesn't quire solve the problem I'm having. I'm currently getting the following error:

```
messages:      100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
numbers:         0% |                                          | ETA:  --:--:--
Saving session to push_201109120849.dat..
!!! Caught Server Exception
HTTP CODE: 500
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  integer out of range
```

And my Numbers migration looks like this:

```
class CreateNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :numbers do |t|
      t.integer :inbound_num
      t.boolean :assigned

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :numbers
  end
end
```

I am using the integer data type to save mobile phone numbers. I am not sure this is a good idea having read this: [What datatype should be used for storing phone numbers in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105/what-datatype-should-be-used-for-storing-phone-numbers-in-sql-server-2005)

The thing is the data works great locally so I don't think I've chosen a terrible data-type.

The numbers in the DB I'm pushing look like this:

447786201383

447786201387

447786201389
 etc...

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration, you've something like

```
t.integer :field
```

But default for Postgresql used on heroku is 4 bytes

So you should change your ints for bigints.

To do that, use the `:limit`. Example:

```
t.integer :field, :limit => 8
```